# How to refer variable in outter scope in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

All:

When I followed coffeescript tutorial on its official website, there is a sample:

```
outer = 1
changeNumbers = ->
  inner = -1
  outer = 10
inner = changeNumbers()
```

Equals:

```
var changeNumbers, inner, outer;

outer = 1;

changeNumbers = function() {
  var inner;
  inner = -1;
  return outer = 10;
};

inner = changeNumbers();
```

I wonder how it looks like in coffeescript if I want to access inner in the outter scope from function changeNumber?

Answer (score 2):

Define `inner` before `changeNumber` and coffeeScript won't see it as an inner variable. For example:

```
outer = 1
inner = 2
changeNumbers = ->
  inner = -1
  outer = 10
inner = changeNumbers()
```

Will compile into something like this:

```
var changeNumbers, inner, outer;

outer = 1;

inner = 2;

changeNumbers = function() {
  inner = -1;
  return outer = 10; 
};

inner = changeNumbers();
```

As mentioned in the CoffeeScript documentation, when writing a deeply nested function, you need to be careful that you're not reusing the name of an external variable accidentally.

Comment: Thanks, what happen if i dont give any value to inner?

Comment: Good point. It won't work. So `inner` would still be declared as an inner variable in `changeNumbers`. Not sure if this behavior was intended.

Comment: You can always write `inner = undefined` or `inner = null`.